# Simple Fixed menu

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hello everyone I am an Italian guy ... I write on this forum because I have a small problem with a fixed menu.

this is my html structure

```
<header>ere is a picture 500px high</header>
<nav>my menu</nav>
```

I have to make this menu fixed when I scroll down.

If I enter this css code

```
nav {
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
 }
```

the menu is positioned at the top of the page (above the header) losing the starting position that is below the header.
The problem is just that!

I have to keep the position but to make fixed header when scroll down.

Is there a way to do that when I scroll down I add a class to the nav tag in such a way as to make it fixed only when it comes out this css class?

Comment: Just take out the `top:0` line of your CSS

Answer (score -1):

you should be doing it correctly, see if my fiddle is what you have!

```
nav {
    position:fixed;
}
```

**DEMO**

http://jsfiddle.net/uJ2tC/

Comment: No this is what I have

http://jsfiddle.net/uJ2tC/1/

and I would like the nav was only fixed when I scoll down the page

Comment: if your image is always a fixed height you can set top of your nav to that height. it will produce the same effect.

Comment: my image is always 100% of the screen.

Comment: just what happens on this site that I would like to get
http://halfcreative.themes.pixelentity.com/
look how does the menu

Comment: Oh ok, you will need to use javascript to detect that and switch the css attribute to fixed as needed.

Comment: Thx so much!!!
And you're able to help me?
I do not understand little of javascript: (